# What model can I build with a limited dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, recommender-system

I have a dataset consisting of purchasing history from an e-commerce website. The columns consist of `customer id`, `product id`, `postal code`, `quantity of products purchased`, `date of the purchase`. There are thousands of different customer ids, hundreds of product ids, and some million rows.

I ran ARIMA modelling for forecasting the purchased quantities of a given product.
Now I want to try other methods for analysing the dataset, but cannot find models which could fit the dataset well. What other models could I run in order to gain more insight on this data?

Comment: Are you familiar with neural networks?

Comment: @Media I am a bit

Comment: Please specify the input and output spaces.

Comment: @Media for example predicting customer churn based on the previous purchases of the customer. I don't really know which of the dataset columns I could use for input. I would guess first I'd need to map the categorical values to integers.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your dataset you can also try to create a product recommendation model so that given a new customer that just purchased a particular item you can predict/suggest or recommend what other items they could purchase next during their shopping trip or after:
- Collaborative filtering can be used to achieve this
- Frequent pattern mining can also be used.

Comment: thank you, could you collaborate on how can those methods be used to achieve that outcome?

Comment: Check this out, there is an example: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html and also: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-frequent-pattern-mining.html